# MFC Application running in embedded mode taking focus

Tags: visual-c++, com, mfc

We have a MFC Application which runs in embedded mode and is invoked by through its COM interface through other applications. In the embedded mode it should not take focus but as we see it is taking up the focus and user keyboard input is changed from the current application to our MFC Application.

I was looking for a workaround, to remove the focus as soon as the MFC application running in embedded gets the focus.

For the workaround, I registered for the OnSetFocus() method by mapping message WM_SETFOCUS and tried to  remove the focus from my MFC application by using following window api SetWindowPos(), but that also does not help.

```
void CTestMFCApplicationView::OnSetFocus(CWnd* pOldWnd)
{
   CView::OnSetFocus(pOldWnd);
   OutputDebugString(L"OnSetFocus\r\n");
   // TODO: Add your message handler code here
   CView::SetWindowPos(&CWnd::wndBottom, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      SWP_NOACTIVATE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is set a breakpoint in OnSetFocus() to see what is triggering the focus to be set.  There might be something you can do there to prevent the focus from being set.

If you can't prevent, then the next option is to react.  I think SetWindowPos() is the wrong way.  The window that previously had the focus is the pOldWnd argument passed in OnSetFocus().  You can try a pOldWnd->SetFocus() instead of the SetWindowPos().  That might work, or it might not.  The better option might be to post a message to yourself, something like WM_USER+1 or WM_APP+1 or a registered message with the HWND of the pOldWnd as your argument.  When you receive that message, use the WinAPI to call ::SetFocus(hWnd).

Comment: As a workaround, i did tried to use pOldWnd->SetFocus() to bring the focus back to the previous window. However I am getting pOldWnd as NULL, therefore this implementation is not working at my end. And I dont understand why I am getting NULL.